Как использовать R в VScode?
Хочу использовать R в VScode, но выдает такую ошибку: VSCode R Session Watcher requires jsonlite, rlang. Please install manually in order to use VSCode-R
Как это установить?

Внезапно, нужно знать как минимум операционку, в которой собираетесь устанавливать пакеты.

Поиск в cran репозитории не пробовали?
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jsonlite/index.html
